# Override create() method in ModelSerializer and get object by ID (Django 3.2)

Tags: python, django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework

**Main Model**

```
class Main(models.Model): 
   title = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
   event = models.ForeignKey('Event', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Event Model**

```
class Event(models.Model):
   day = models.DateField(u'Day of the event', help_text=u'Day of the event', null=True)
```

**JSON Structure example:**

```
{    
   "titre": "main",
   "event": {
        "id": 13, #can't filter or get object by id
        "day": "2022-01-30"
    }
}
```

**Override create() in Serializer:**

```
class MainSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    event = EventSerializer()

    class Meta: 
        model = Main
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        event_data = validated_data.pop('event')
        event = Event.objects.get(id=event_data['id'])
        main = Main.objects.create(event=event, **validated_data)
        return main
```

Event Serializer:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 

class Meta: 
    model = Event
    fields = '__all__'
```

So I encounter an error "*KeyError id*" and I can't add the object.

Comment: Did you check if you have `event_data` in `create()` method?

Comment: I'm using this condition, but since I can't access `event_data['id']` it doesn't work: `if Event.objects.filter(id = event_data['id']).exists():`

When I try for example `event = Event.objects.get(id=13)` it works fine. So I think that the problem is accessing the event primary key.

Comment: Can you share your `EventSerializer`?

Comment: @BrianDestura I just added EventSerializer

Comment: Have you tried `even_data = json.loads(validated_data.pop('event'))` and then try to get your id and don't forget to `import json`

Comment: @Ahtisham I got the error: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not OrderedDict

Comment: so `event_data` is `OrderedDict` can you print it and show me its value. try this `validated_data[0].pop('event')`

Comment: @Ahtisham trying to get the first record doesn't work also. 

For the event_data value: `'event'= {OrderedDict([('day', datetime.date(2022, 1, 30)), ('start_time', datetime.time(10, 4, 18)), ('end_time', datetime.time(12, 0)), ('notes', 'description')])}`. It seems there is no ID for event.

Comment: Try adding an `id` field explicitly, using `id = serializers.IntegerField()`

Comment: @Ersain It doesn't seem to work.. It tells me that ID is a required field, even if the JSON structure displays it.

Comment: @Ersain So after retrying, it works! I will add your answer as the solution for my question

Answer (score 0):

The solution was quite simple : just add this line to the EventSerializer

```
id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
```